# What should I do if I can't find the GPUImage.h header for the GPUImage framework?

Tags: objective-c, ios, filter

I have created a sample application to perform bump distortion, using the [GPUImage framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). I added this framework to my application, but I'm seeing the following error

> Lexical or preprocessor issue 'GPUImage.h' file not found.

I have added the `-ObjC` flag to the Other Linker Flags, but I'm still seeing this error. How can I solve this problem and get my application to compile?

Answer (score 30):

Adding GPUImage framework to XCode project could be tricky. So I haved added detailed step-by-step instructions w/ images on how to do it.

**Static Compilation Method (detailed solution so we don't mess up)**

This is Static compilation method. In this basically we will compile the framework using ./build.sh file. And simply add it to our XCode project, then configure XCode to properly use it.

1. Download GPUImage from Github and extract it (or just clone it).
2. Go to the `GPUImage`folder in terminal
3. Run **./build.sh**

   *Note: This will compile and create ready-to-use binary for all the sdks  on your mac.*
4. build.sh creates a folder called **build** and generates compiled binaries and dumps them to folders like: **Release-iPhone**, **Release-iPhoneOS**, **Release-iphonesimulator** etc folders.
   [image]
5. For iPhone use  **Release-iphone** (This also works for simulator).
6. Copy (not drag-drop) **Release-iphone** to your XCode project's root directory so that we have a local copy of framework.
7. Now iPhone drag-and-drop **Release-iphone**   onto your XCode project. Make sure to check "Copy to .." option.

   Note:

   - This **Release-iphone** folder contains two sub-folders: **include** and **lib**
   - **include** folder contains all the header **.h** files
   - **lib** folder contains compiled binary version file called **libGPUImage.a**
   - We now need to simply configure XCode to use .h and .a files.**
8. Select your project in the project explorer > Project name under **Targets** > select Build Phases > Expand **Link Binary With Libraries**
9. Add the **libGPUImage.a** to Link Binary With Libraries section. You may want to Right-click on **libGPUImage.a** then **Open in Finder** and finally drag-drop it.
10. While we are at it, also add the following GPUImage's dependent frameworks/ libraries 
    **CoreMedia, CoreVideo, OpenGLES, AVFoundation, QuartzCore**  to **Link Binary With Libraries** section
    [image]
11. Now, lets configure **.h** headers.
12. Select your project in the project explorer > Project name under **Targets** > select Build Settings > and type *search paths* to see **search paths** section.
13. Open **Headers Search Paths** by clicking on the value field.
14. Drag-and-drop the **lib** folder to that popup. Note: If it shows absolute path, change it to looks **$(SRCROOT)/path/to/lib/**. (You should have the framework relative to your xcode project see step 6).
15. Repeat 11 & 12 for **Library Search Paths** as well.

[image]
Additional tips: You can add **.h** files to **Library Search Paths** or **Headers Search Paths**, you can make them **Recursive**. I have a main root-folder called **Dependencies** folder where I keep all the dependencies like MySDK-framework including Release-iPhone. And I just have one search-path at the Dependencies (root folder) and made it **recursive**.

Comment: This is simply one of the best answers i have seen on SO.

Comment: @MrSMAK Thanks. It took a while for me to figure it out :)

Comment: i'm still getting the GPUImage.h not found error i did step by step but same problem

Comment: @DekelMaman I'm pretty sure you are one of the above steps. Double check slowly.

Comment: @RajaRao yeah you right i missed something thanks ;)

Comment: Got error :xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphoneos7.0" cannot be located. in terminal when ./build.sh

Comment: @Hector, hey Hector, Can you explain what thing you changed in ./build.sh please?

Comment: @Hector i've Xcode6.4 and iOS8.4. i changed IOSSDK_VER=“7.0” to "8.4" but still got xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphoneos“8.4”" cannot be located.

Comment: Got error when run this command on terminal ./build.sh  . =>xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphoneos9.0" cannot be located.

Answer (score 6):

Did you follow all of the instructions from the Readme on the [project page](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)? From the installation instructions:

> You'll also need to find the framework headers, so within your
>   project's build settings set the Header Search Paths to the relative
>   path from your application to the framework/ subdirectory within the
>   GPUImage source directory. Make this header search path recursive.

If you're seeing the above error, it means that you did not point the Header Search Paths at the right directory where you've installed GPUImage relative to your project, and / or did not click the checkbox to the left to make those search paths recursive.

I show some screenshots of where you need to go to set this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10261140/19679), which explains something similar for the Core Plot framework. The same principles apply, only you need to find where you installed the GPUImage framework at.

Answer (score 5):

I add relative path to "Header Search Paths", but there is still a error that is "not found".

Then, I add path to "User Header Search Paths", and it works.

May help you.

[image]

Comment: Did this also and it worked, then it seemed to remove itself from "User Header Search Paths"...strange. Thanks though for mentioning that.

Answer (score 2):

finally, I realized the KEY WORD is `relative`！
I put GPUImage source files in my project root dir:
[image]

before I solved the problem, I add Header Search Paths is:

`$(PROJECT_DIR)/GPUImage/framework`

`$(PROJECT_DIR)/GPUImage/framework/iOS`

and make them Recursive, but error is still there, So I changed Paths to:

`GPUImage/framework` and make it Recursive, then it works.

Hope it helps.