# How to solve the architecture i386 linker error while using GPUImage?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, gpuimage

I am using the GPUImage for filtering of the image ,I integrated GPUImage in my project its integrated perfectly ,now i want access the file of GPUImage into my code.I was getting the linker error.

[image]

While i was using this code in my viewcontroller

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    GPUImageFilter *selectedFilter;

    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImageGrayscaleFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 1:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 2:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImageSketchFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 3:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImagePixellateFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 4:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImageColorInvertFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 5:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImageToonFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 6:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImagePinchDistortionFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 7:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    UIImage *filteredImage = [selectedFilter imageByFilteringImage:self.imgViewPhoto.image];
    [self.imgViewPhoto setImage:filteredImage];
}
```

how to solve this problem ?Waiting for the answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GPUImage` framework is not added to your project Target.

[Adding the framework to your iOS project](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

```
Start by dragging the GPUImage.xcodeproj file into your application's Xcode project to embed the framework in your project. 
Next, go to your application's target and add GPUImage as a Target Dependency. 
Finally, you'll want to drag the libGPUImage.a library from the GPUImage framework's Products folder to the Link Binary With Libraries build phase in your application's target.
```

And of course : `#import "GPUImage.h"`

Answer (score 2):

Error says that you miss any framework to add  in your project for use of `GPUImage`

Generally  `GPUImage`  require/use following framework

> - CoreMedia
> - CoreVideo
> - OpenGLES
> - AVFoundation
> - QuartzCore

Check which framework is missed by you ?? and add it such like

- Select the project in the project navigator sidebar.
- Click on the "Build Phases" tab.
- Expand the "Link Binary With Libraries" section.
- Click the '+' button.
- Choose 'missed frmework' from the list.

And then add `#import "GPUImage.h"` in your **.m** file.

Answer (score 0):

I have added detailed steps w/ pictures to import GPUImage framework here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21896243/1553014