# GPUImage issues running on simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios6, gpuimage

So I've been trying to get GPUImage library to work in a project, and whilst it works on the device, does not work on simulator. I've tried in Xcode 5, using both Retina and non-retina simulators and get the following error:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageBuffer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in StartViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageVideoCamera", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in StartViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in StartViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageiOSBlurFilter", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in StartViewController.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image: Build Settings]

My Build Settings are as follows;
[image: Settings]

I need for this to run on simulator as well as on device. I have tried making Build Active Architecture Only NO, as well as playing around with Valid Architectures, to have armv7 by itself, armv7 and armv7s, and just armv64, but to no avail.

Any help would be amazing.
Thanks in advance

Comment: OK finally worked it out, and was answered at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382394/what-should-i-do-if-i-cant-find-the-gpuimage-h-header-for-the-gpuimage-framewor

Answer (score 3):

Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries ...then add "GPUImage.framework", "libGPUImage.a"

Answer (score 2):

I just deleted "arm64" from "Valid Architectures" and it works for me now. Maybe it helps.