# How to get brightness level form UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, tesseract, brightness

How can I get the brightness level form an UIImage. Actually I am trying to get brightness level and then set it to some other level (using GPUImage framework), So that I can pass that image to tessaract OCR SDK.

Comment: To be clear, what are you referring to as brightness? Luminance?  intensity of the pixels?

Comment: If you're looking for the average luminosity, you can use a GPUImageLuminosity filter to extract that, as I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610744/luminosity-from-ios-camera/14612913#14612913 . After that, an exposure or brightness filter can normalize this to a set average luminosity.

Answer (score -1):

To modifify the brightness of an image, the solution that you're searching for is applying a filter over your original image. 
This can be achieved by using the filter class provided in the CoreImage framework, more specifically CIFilter. Take a quick peek over the documentation, it's pretty straight-forward. 
If you don't with to use CoreImage, there's several examples on the web with already written filters, however, I think the CIFilter class should be enough.

Comment: I am looking for getting brightness level no setting brightness level. I can set brightness level using GPUImage framework