# Library not found for

Tags: ios, objective-c, path, core-plot, linker-errors

I'm working on an application in which I need to use `CorePlot`. I downloaded the last version of it, and added the `CorePlot` headers folder and `lib.a` file to my project.

I correctly add

```
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
```

in my view controller, and remove the library search path and framework search path from my project.

However, I still have the error:

```
ld: library not found for -lCorePlot-CocoaTouch
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What would be the problem be?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show you "Library Search Paths" build setting?  This path is used to find the lib.a file.

Comment: I have deleted the item into Library Search Paths, as I seen it could be one of the solution

Comment: You should make the library search path setting include the path where the library.a file.

Comment: I tried /Users/myUserName/Desktop/myAppName/CorePlotHeaders/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a  but it steel doesn't work

Comment: If you upload a zip of the app or put something up on Github, I can take a look at it. Otherwise this will be hard to figure out.

Comment: I can't send it it's link with a server with passwords etc...

Comment: Gotcha, well you should look at this and ask the creators of coreplot https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications

Comment: What I think is doesn't work is the header search path parameter. I drag the xcode project of core plot into my project, but i don't find the core plot folder and framework as in this example : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260291/installing-core-plot-in-xcode-4-2-for-ios-project)

Comment: Is `libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a` listed in the "Link Binaries With Libraries" build phase? If not, click the "+" and add it to the list.

Comment: It is listed. I have the "missing required architecture x86_64 in file" error now...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and I found out that I didn't open the project properly. Instead of double clicking on the project.xcodeproj file. Go to Xcode.

Go to File > Open and navigate to the root directory of your project. Press open when the xcode.proj is visible and it should work.

Comment: thanks so much. i would have spent hours trying to debug for no reason.